# Add Tables to Trix Text Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

I'm using text editor Trix in my Ruby Code, and I need to add a table's feature, does anyone know how to include it in the `richtext.js`?
Thanks so much for your help, let me know if you need more information

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UQLc.png

Answer (score 0):

Basecamp doesn't currently support this yet, as the trix editor does not support tables directly.
https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/539

There are some custom solutions, we are exploring, but have not yet implemented
https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/10/26/build-a-table-editor-with-trix-and-turbo-frames-in-rails.html